# EKG reading question

Tags: cardiology, heart, heart-rate, electrocardiogram, heartbeat

Can someone tell me what "ETRSR1-RSR' in V1 or V2, right VCD or RVH-QRS area positive & R' V1/V2 " means? In other comments it also said "otherwise normal EKG"